plot(): adjust vertical space on Y-axis
How to adjust the vertical space between labels as well as data points within my plot?
Some example data:
data <- data.frame(
  a = c(-2.5, -1.2, 0, 1.4, 2.8),
  b = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5")  
)

plot(
  data$a,                         
  seq_along(data$a),         
  xaxt = "n",                      
  yaxt = "n"                     
)
axis(2, at = seq_along(data$b), labels = data$b, las = 2)

which produces:

I have no clue how to adjust this.

You have categorical y variables, so your y axis values are 1,2,3,4,5. So you could shrink the distance artificially by multiplying by 0.5 (at = seq_along(data$b)*0.5) but the visual would look the same because the y axis limits would just automatically adjust.
I think what you want to do is save the plot using different aspect ratios. For example:
jpeg(filename = 'junk.jpg', res = 800,
    height = 7, width = 12, units = 'in')

plot(
  data$a,                         
  seq_along(data$a),         
  xaxt = "n",                      
  yaxt = "n"                     
)
axis(2, at = seq_along(data$b), labels = data$b, las = 2)

dev.off()

This results in:

AND:
jpeg(filename = 'junk.jpeg', res = 800,
    height = 4, width = 8, units = 'in') # Change vertical size

plot(
  data$a,                         
  seq_along(data$a),         
  xaxt = "n",                      
  yaxt = "n"                     
)
axis(2, at = seq_along(data$b), labels = data$b, las = 2)

dev.off()

results in :

hope that helps!

If you're using R studio, using the export -­­> export as image will allow you to set the view port size, hence "squeezing" the graph that you had.
You can also play with the axis by defining a plot window and setting an aspect ratio:
plot(
  data$a,                         
  seq_along(data$a),         
  plot.window(c(-3,3), c(1, 7)),
  omd = c(0.3,0.3,0.12,0.3),
  xaxt = "n",                      
  yaxt = "n", asp=0.75
)
axis(2, at = seq_along(data$b), labels = data$b, las = 2)

Say if you wanted more space for an overly long title.
